# Hard-coded URL to test connectivity

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I was looking at the code [here](https://github.com/MikeCodesDotNet/App-Service-Helpers/blob/master/Azure.Mobile/Tables/BaseTableDataStore.cs) from `xamarin` training [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/add-a-backend-to-your-app-in-10-minutes/) and as I'm going through the code (for my own educational purposes), I noticed this line (line 42)

```
public async virtual Task Sync()
    {
        var connected = await Plugin.Connectivity.CrossConnectivity.Current.IsReachable("google.com");
        if (connected == false)
            return;
```

I could be wrong..but to me, it looks like the only purpose of it to test connectivity.  Is there a better way to do this than hard-code `google.com` just to see if there is a connection?  Is there a flag somewhere that one can test for that?   What if `google` is down (ignore the tear in space-time continuum)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not uncommon.  For instance, iOS and Mac will make a connection to `http://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html` or `http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html` or some other URL on behalf of the user when joining a Wi-Fi network to see if the network has Internet connectivity and also to detect captive portals.  Microsoft and Android devices do something similar, just with a different known URL.

It's probably best to try and connect to a service you control, since in general if your app is useless if it can't make a connection to yourapp.com, it's best to make sure you can connect to yourapp.com.

Doing the test to see if google.com is available is a reasonable fallback to see if the device has 'connectivity', though.

Comment: A footnote to this, the code in question is gone.  See https://github.com/MikeCodesDotNet/App-Service-Helpers/commit/c0eeecebab7671d5b02020b6e8b8bce002bc3008 I guess there was no need for it after all.

Answer (score 3):

If you are testing connectivity so that you can test that your Azure Mobile App is up, replace google.com with the URL of the service.  It seems that is really want you want to be testing.

Comment: Having "a connection" probably isn't all that useful if you can't connect to what you really need to use (your service layer). I like this answer.